# TinyMCE with CDN on Contao 3.x

Tags: tinymce, xss, cdn, contao

I have a Contao 3.x website where I use CDN for the assets. The problem that gives rise to on the backend is that TinyMCE does not work anymore. I read that there is a different cdn js for loading TinyMCE with CDN, but on a Contao (or probably the same with any other CMS using TinyMCE), and especially the backend, something like that is auto configured by the system. I could try to make a core change inserting a script tag on the template, but that is not optimal at all and not what I am looking for as a solution.
Anyone knows if there is a workaround with Access Control or something? I use Amazon CDN.

Comment: All my asset files (js, css) are hosted on CDN. Therefore, the TinyMCE javascripts are also served through the CDN.

Comment: Which Contao version do you use exactly?