# how to load assets and files from cdn in contao to increase page speed

Tags: contao

I am using contao 4.5.8 . Can I use the root configuration " Assets URL " 
to load my assets from a cdn ? Any other configuration needed for my  requirement ? I fount an issue belongs to [TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628631/tinymce-with-cdn-on-contao-3-x) ,is this fixed ? And I also need to know alternatives for rackspace .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contao supports a [Pull CDN](https://cdn.net/push-vs-pull-cdn/) via the *Files URL* & *Assets URL* in the website root configuration, yes. No further configuration on Contao's side is required. As the names suggest, the *Files URL* will be prepended to any URL pointing to the `files` directory, while the *Assets URL* will be prepended to any URL pointing to the `assets` directory.

On a side note: Contao 4.5 already [reached the end of its life](https://contao.org/en/release-plan.html) a few months ago, you should update to Contao 4.6.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.